# Formatting date from INTEGER field in SqLite database (iTunes backup)

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, itunes

I am looking at my yesterday iPhone backup file using SQLite Maestro, and the date field shows INTEGER numbers - e.g. the date of my last SMS message shows as 404076049. How do I convert it to a readable datetime?
I found somewhere an example `SELECT strftime("%m-%d-%Y", date_col, 'unixepoch') AS date_col` but that convert the aforementioned number to 12-31-1982, which is definitely wrong (date should be some time yesterday)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mac uses a different "epoch time" than the UNIX epoch time.

The UNIX epoch date is Midnight January 1, 1970 UTC (aka Greenwich Mean Time)

The Mac OS epoch date is Midnight January 1, 2001 UTC.

I don't know how to convert a date from integer format to date string using SQL statements, but I do know how to do it using Cocoa:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: intValue];
```

You should be able to calculate the difference between the 2 date systems and apply that as a conversion factor:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval secondsSince2001 = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval secondsSince1970 = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
long int difference = trunc(secondsSince2001 - secondsSince1970);
```

You could then add "difference" to your integer values before using it in your select statement.

Comment: But you gave me an idea - difference between those two epoh dates is 978,307,200 seconds. So, I can add that to my INT date: `SELECT strftime("%m-%d-%Y", date + 978307200, 'unixepoch') AS date_1`. I am checking off your answer, thank you!

Comment: Andrey's SQL worked well for me - I'm building a log of messages from a text message history, which I grabbed from my iphone backup. iPhones are silly about not showing the actual timestamps of each message, but this approach lets me export directly to a spreadsheet with accurate times.

Comment: I wanted it all in one line, so: `sqlite3 -csv -header filename 'select message.handle_id, message.subject, message.text, strftime("%m-%d-%Y,%H:%M", message.date + 978307200, "unixepoch") as date_1, message.is_from_me, handle.rowid, handle.id from message, handle where message.handle_id = handle.rowid;'`

Comment: Updating Audrey's SQL for Mohave (and year/month/day): `SELECT strftime("%Y-%m-%d", (date + 978307200000000000) / 1000000000, 'unixepoch') AS date_1 from message`

Answer (score 0):

So based on Audrey's comment, to do this in SQL (with the new nanoseconds timestamps in MacOS Mohave):

```
SELECT strftime("%Y-%m-%d", (date / 1000000000) + 978307200, 'unixepoch')
  AS date_1 from message
```